# How to Quickly Draw Temporary Squiggles, Lines and Arrows on Desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, software-rec, presentations

During remote training sessions, instructors often draw red squiggly lines or circles on their desktop to emphasize key ideas.  This helps offsite viewers better understand what an instructor is talking about when that remote instructor is sharing her/his desktop.

Where can I get a program for MS Windows that will allow me to temporarily draw circles, boxes, and the like around elements of my desktop?

Comment: They are most likely using the annotation features of conferencing solutions such as GoToMeeting or Webex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[zoomit from system internals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897434) would do the trick - its mainly for freeform drawing, but would let you annotate a screen directly

[image]